# NSURL initFileURLWithPath nil string parameter Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a crash problem in my app and I don't know where to start.

this happened when my app show and the app crash , and suddenly the app run without this crash for 1-3 days and suddenly the problem return.

- in My code i don't use initFileURLWithPath.
- the project runs in Xcode 7.

  2015-10-13 17:09:08.856 Stardust[8627:4500164] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (0x186380f5c 0x19af77f80 0x186380ea4 0x18722a934 0x18722a8a0 0x10032d9fc 0x1006a9d30 0x1006b588c 0x10032d8fc 0x100291b18 0x1006a9d70 0x1006a9d30 0x1006b8f38 0x1006b8600 0x19b985478 0x19b985028)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Set Breakpoint exception to find the line. `initFileURLWithPath:` could be called in third library or is "hidden" inside another method.

Comment: like this ? http://puu.sh/kINE5/df2c0b2d16.png